# MissingMethodException isStartOnPluginLoad() for gsp-resources-0.4.2 plugin

Tags: grails

gsp-resources plugin version - 0.4.2

Grails version - 2.2.4

I gave 'utils' plugin that use gspResources plugin.
And 'utils' plugin is used in application.
I can not start (grails run-app) grails application because of error in plugin, but building war is OK. (grails war)

Previously it was working, but after some change (that i can not identify ) app fails to start.

```
| Error 2013-09-16 12:20:54,062 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR plugins.DefaultGrailsPluginManager - Error configuring dynamic methods for plugin [gspResources:0.4.2]: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: org.grails.plugin.resource.ResourceProcessor.isStartOnPluginLoad() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
Message: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: org.grails.plugin.resource.ResourceProcessor.isStartOnPluginLoad() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
Line | Method
->> 334 | innerRun in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync

| 166 | run in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
| 1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
| 615 | run in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^ 722 | run . . . in java.lang.Thread

Caused by MissingMethodException: No signature of method: org.grails.plugin.resource.ResourceProcessor.isStartOnPluginLoad() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
->> 59 | doCall in GspResourcesGrailsPlugin$_closure2

| 334 | innerRun in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
| 166 | run . . . in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
| 1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
| 615 | run . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^ 722 | run in java.lang.Thread
2013-09-16 12:20:54,135 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO resource.ResourceProcessor - Performing a full reload
| Error 2013-09-16 12:20:55,983 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR resource.ResourceProcessor - Unable to load resources
Message: Error creating bean with name 'org.grails.plugin.gspresources.GspResourceMapper': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.grails.plugin.gspresources.GspResourceMapperInstance' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.grails.plugin.gspresources.GspResourceMapperInstance': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.ConversionNotSupportedException: Failed to convert property value of type 'org.grails.plugin.resource.ResourceProcessor' to required type 'org.grails.plugin.gspresources.GspResourceProcessor' for property 'grailsResourceProcessor'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [org.grails.plugin.resource.ResourceProcessor] to required type [org.grails.plugin.gspresources.GspResourceProcessor] for property 'grailsResourceProcessor': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
Line | Method
->> 593 | createApplicationContext in grails.spring.BeanBuilder

| 43 | createResourceMappers in org.grails.plugin.resource.mapper.ResourceMappersFactory
| 1005 | loadMappers . . . . . . in org.grails.plugin.resource.ResourceProcessor
| 1074 | reloadAll in ''
| 172 | doCall . . . . . . . . . in ResourcesGrailsPlugin$_closure3
| 334 | innerRun in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
| 166 | run . . . . . . . . . . in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
| 1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
| 615 | run . . . . . . . . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^ 722 | run in java.lang.Thread

Caused by BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.grails.plugin.gspresources.GspResourceMapperInstance': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.ConversionNotSupportedException: Failed to convert property value of type 'org.grails.plugin.resource.ResourceProcessor' to required type 'org.grails.plugin.gspresources.GspResourceProcessor' for property 'grailsResourceProcessor'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [org.grails.plugin.resource.ResourceProcessor] to required type [org.grails.plugin.gspresources.GspResourceProcessor] for property 'grailsResourceProcessor': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
->> 593 | createApplicationContext in grails.spring.BeanBuilder

| 43 | createResourceMappers in org.grails.plugin.resource.mapper.ResourceMappersFactory
| 1005 | loadMappers . . . . . . in org.grails.plugin.resource.ResourceProcessor
| 1074 | reloadAll in ''
| 172 | doCall . . . . . . . . . in ResourcesGrailsPlugin$_closure3
| 334 | innerRun in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
| 166 | run . . . . . . . . . . in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
| 1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
| 615 | run . . . . . . . . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^ 722 | run in java.lang.Thread

Caused by ConversionNotSupportedException: Failed to convert property value of type 'org.grails.plugin.resource.ResourceProcessor' to required type 'org.grails.plugin.gspresources.GspResourceProcessor' for property 'grailsResourceProcessor'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [org.grails.plugin.resource.ResourceProcessor] to required type [org.grails.plugin.gspresources.GspResourceProcessor] for property 'grailsResourceProcessor': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
->> 593 | createApplicationContext in grails.spring.BeanBuilder

| 43 | createResourceMappers in org.grails.plugin.resource.mapper.ResourceMappersFactory
| 1005 | loadMappers . . . . . . in org.grails.plugin.resource.ResourceProcessor
| 1074 | reloadAll in ''
| 172 | doCall . . . . . . . . . in ResourcesGrailsPlugin$_closure3
| 334 | innerRun in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
| 166 | run . . . . . . . . . . in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
| 1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
| 615 | run . . . . . . . . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^ 722 | run in java.lang.Thread

Caused by IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [org.grails.plugin.resource.ResourceProcessor] to required type [org.grails.plugin.gspresources.GspResourceProcessor] for property 'grailsResourceProcessor': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
->> 593 | createApplicationContext in grails.spring.BeanBuilder

| 43 | createResourceMappers in org.grails.plugin.resource.mapper.ResourceMappersFactory
| 1005 | loadMappers . . . . . . in org.grails.plugin.resource.ResourceProcessor
| 1074 | reloadAll in ''
| 172 | doCall . . . . . . . . . in ResourcesGrailsPlugin$_closure3
| 334 | innerRun in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
| 166 | run . . . . . . . . . . in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
| 1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
| 615 | run . . . . . . . . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^ 722 | run in java.lang.Thread
2013-09-16 12:21:03,785 [localhost-startStop-1] WARN util.GrailsUtil - [DEPRECATED] Method ConfigurationHolder.getConfig() is deprecated and will be removed in a future version of Grails.
2013-09-16 12:21:03,800 [localhost-startStop-1] WARN util.GrailsUtil - [DEPRECATED] Method ApplicationHolder.getApplication() is deprecated and will be removed in a future version of Grails.
2013-09-16 12:21:03,815 [localhost-startStop-1] WARN util.GrailsUtil - [DEPRECATED] Method ApplicationHolder.getApplication() is deprecated and will be removed in a future version of Grails.
2013-09-16 12:21:03,820 [localhost-startStop-1] WARN util.GrailsUtil - [DEPRECATED] Method ConfigurationHolder.getConfig() is deprecated and will be removed in a future version of Grails.
2013-09-16 12:21:03,821 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO CacheHeadersGrailsPlugin - Caching enabled in Config: true
2013-09-16 12:21:07,547 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO context.GrailsConfigUtils - [GrailsContextLoader] Grails application loaded.
| Error 2013-09-16 12:21:07,665 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR context.GrailsContextLoader - Error initializing the application: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: org.grails.plugin.resource.ResourceProcessor.isStartOnPluginBootstrap() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
Message: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: org.grails.plugin.resource.ResourceProcessor.isStartOnPluginBootstrap() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
Line | Method
->> 308 | evaluateEnvironmentSpecificBlock in grails.util.Environment

| 301 | executeForEnvironment in ''
| 277 | executeForCurrentEnvironment . . in ''
| 334 | innerRun in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
| 166 | run . . . . . . . . . . . . . . in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
| 1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
| 615 | run . . . . . . . . . . . . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^ 722 | run in java.lang.Thread

Caused by MissingMethodException: No signature of method: org.grails.plugin.resource.ResourceProcessor.isStartOnPluginBootstrap() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
->> 12 | doCall in GspResourcesBootStrap$_closure1

| 308 | evaluateEnvironmentSpecificBlock in grails.util.Environment
| 301 | executeForEnvironment . . . . . in ''
| 277 | executeForCurrentEnvironment in ''
| 334 | innerRun . . . . . . . . . . . . in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
| 166 | run in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
| 1145 | runWorker . . . . . . . . . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
| 615 | run in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^ 722 | run . . . . . . . . . . . . . . in java.lang.Thread
2013-09-16 12:21:07,786 [UaalClientService STOPPING] INFO service.UaalClientService - Stoping UAAL Client Service
2013-09-16 12:21:07,786 [UaalClientService STOPPING] INFO service.UaalClientService - Service was stopped, tasks never started: []
2013-09-16 12:21:07,797 [Thread-9] INFO impl.SessionFactoryImpl - closing
2013-09-16 12:21:07,817 [Thread-9] INFO impl.SessionFactoryImpl - closing
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was in loading order of plugins.
Is fixed in gsp-resources version 0.4.3

https://github.com/mckenfra/gsp-resources/issues/7